# How can a Button Submit at the same time toggles a modal

Tags: php

after i click only the modal is executed but the form is not submitted, what are the possible errors in my code?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">
    <form action="{{url('accept/invoice')}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$in->c_id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{$in->c_quantity}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alert  btn-circle">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</a>
```

Comment: <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript and jquery

first add an id to your form e.g:`id="myform"`

than change submit button type to button: `type="submit"` => `type="button"`

finally call java script function with onclick attribute, the code should be like this:

```
 <form action="{{url('accept/invoice')}}" method="post" id="myform">
    {{csrf_field()}}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$in->c_id}}">
     <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{$in->c_quantity}}">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-alert  btn-circle" onclick="my_function();">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function() {
        $("#myModal").modal("toggle");
        $("#myform").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try add id to your form  tag e.g.

```
<form action="{{url('accept/invoice')}}" id="form1" method="post">
```

Then add the id to your button tag

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-alert  btn-circle" form="form1">
 <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">
when i toggle the button sir is that it will only excute the modal and it wont execute the form inside the button as i click it

Comment: You can use the Jquery onClick function to execute your code once you click the button. $("#buttonId").click(function(e){ $("#myModal").modal("toggle");
         $("#myform").submit();  });